How to speed up SQL query with multiple joins
My SQL Server was upgraded over the last few days to 2019 version.
I don't run this query often, so I don't know whether it was faster before the migration.
The following query takes 45+ seconds to run, directly in SSMS, and in a web environment lands up giving a SQL timeout error.
The tables all join onto table tblGivingContacts using their respective primary key (eg, tblStudents.studentID, tblGivingCampaigns.campaignID, tblGivingCallStatus.callStatusID, tblGivingDonationStatus.donationStatusID).
My query:
SELECT DISTINCT 
    tblGivingContacts.[ID], tblGivingContacts.[contactID],
    tblGivingContacts.[contactType], tblGivingContacts.[contactTypeSub],
    tblGivingContacts.[lastUpdated], 
    tblGivingContacts.[DonationCurrency],
    tblGivingContacts.[DonationAmount], 
    tblGivingContacts.[Notes], tblGivingContacts.[ProcessedBy],
    tblGivingContacts.[scheduleID], 
    firstname, lastname, fathersname, mothersname,  
    email, fathersemail, mothersemail, 
    DonationStatusName, callStatusName, CampaignName,  
    phone1, phone2, cellphone, 
    FathersCellphone, MothersCellphone, 
    tblStudents.Country AS StudentCountry, 
    tblAlumni.Country AS AlumniCountry, 
    MothersCountry, FathersCountry,
    (SELECT TOP 1 SchoolYear 
     FROM tblStudentStudyYears 
     WHERE tblStudentStudyYears.studentID = tblStudents.studentID 
     ORDER BY schoolYear DESC) AS SchoolYear  
FROM 
    [tblGivingContacts] 
INNER JOIN 
    tblStudents ON tblGivingContacts.contactID = tblStudents.studentID 
INNER JOIN 
    tblParents ON tblParents.studentID = tblStudents.studentID 
INNER JOIN 
    tblGivingCampaigns ON tblGivingContacts.campaignID = tblGivingCampaigns.campaignID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    tblAlumni ON tblAlumni.studentID = tblStudents.studentID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    tblGivingCallStatus ON tblGivingContacts.callStatusID = tblGivingCallStatus.callStatusID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    tblGivingDonationStatus ON tblGivingContacts.donationStatusID = tblGivingDonationStatus.donationStatusID

I have looked at the execution plan, the main things that come out are:

tblGivingContacts.* cost = 38%
the tblParents columns cost = 27%

Adding some profiler info for this query:

Execution plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=B1YutO57R
And this is what the execution plans suggested:
Missing Index Details from SQLQuery1.sql 
The Query Processor estimates that implementing the following index could improve the query cost by 28.7418%.
*/

/*
USE [database]
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [<Name of Missing Index, sysname,>]
ON [dbo].[tblParents] ([studentID])
INCLUDE ([FathersName],[FathersCountry],[FathersEmail],[FathersCellphone],[MothersName],[MothersCountry],[MothersEmail],[MothersCellphone])

Is this something that's suggested? Is there any detriment to doing this? What if I land up changing the query/adding columns in the Select?

Adding indexes can help, but you have to look at what/how  big the index will be and what/how it could impact other queries hitting this table (and how big the tables are).  It can be good idea (especially if you dont already have indexes).    If you dont need to select * for the one table though I would reduce that to just the columns you need, especially with DISTINCT.

Doesn't seem like tblParents have clustered index on StudentID. Is there a non-clustered index on it? It might be already enough without including a bunch of columns

@Brad - correct, i just removed the * and replaced with the individual columns I need, but no difference to the result/speed.

@siggemannen- there is no non-clustered index on tblParents.StudentID. There could be multiple rows with the same tblParents.StudentID, (ie, multiple parents for the same student), but still only one primary index of tblParents.ParentID - do you still suggest creating this non-clustered index ? i have never used these before.

Can you upload the actual execution plan to https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ ? So we can see the bits that are actually taking the time

Do you actually need DISTINCT?

That's the estimated execution plan. The "Actual" one contains timings for each operator and shows where the estimated vs actual rows are different. The scans on the inside of nested loops could definitely be problematic but the actual plan will show the timings these take

@MartinSmith - Re DISTINCT - there are 3 rows more in the query without the DISTINCT. How do I generate the 'Actual' plan?

In SSMS on the Query menu there is an option to include it and then just run the query as normal

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/display-an-actual-execution-plan?view=sql-server-ver16   then https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/instructions/    click on the Execution Plan tab, right-click on the plan, and click View XML. Copy all of that.

@MartinSmith- updated: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=B1YutO57R

Thanks, you can easily see the issues when looking at it (some time consuming scans as no useful indexes and very wrong one row estimate meaning nested loops is still used despite the scans) https://i.sstatic.net/pE7yjMfg.png

@MartinSmith , thank you. I honestly don't understand this or what our recommendation is to fix?

You need to either try and get better estimates for the join between tblGivingContacts and tblGivingCampaigns (estimates 1 row vs reality 12,093) or supply useful indexes that would allow those time consuming scans to be seeked. I see the plan has CardinalityEstimationModelVersion="70" so you could see whether the more recent cardinality estimator has better estimates for that join

Thank for your time on this @MartinSmith. Looks like I have a lot to learn as most of what you said does not mean much to me yet.

To see if the 2019 cardinality estimator does a better job of estimating the number of rows from  the join between tblGivingContacts and tblGivingCampaigns you can add OPTION ( USE HINT ( 'QUERY_OPTIMIZER_COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL_150' )); to the end of the query. Likely if it "knew" that this would return 12,093 rows it wouldn't opt to scan those tables multiple times anyway

@MartinSmith - Thank you! I added that and the query completed in 1 second via SSMS!
Is this an option i can enable on the entire database settings? Also - seems this was related to the migration?

If you just upgraded version then it is recommended to update statistics - so you could try that and see if that fixes the estimation issue with the old cardinality estimator too.  If it was using the "old" CE pre-upgrade then in theory the plans shouldn't change otherwise between versions. You should look into why it is using the old CE. Likely the database compat level is set to something low and you could consider upgrading (after getting a baseline in querystore to identify regressions)

The "new" cardinality estimator isn't always more accurate than the legacy CE so you should definitely get a baseline in querystore before upgrading so you can see any queries that have regressed and potentially force the old plans on them

Thanks again @MartinSmith - I'd be happy to grant you the answer if possible

The important part of the index is the CREATE INDEX name ON tblParents(studentID). The INCLUDE (...) part is optional. When present, the INCLUDE can save a key lookup step in the execution plan to retrieve the necessary columns from that table needed to complete execution. I usually don't bother with included columns and just let the key lookup do its thing, except in very specific cases (such as junction tables and where a few included columns can support filtering of data before retrieval). I specifically avoid including large numbers of columns on wide tables just to save a lookup.

From a manual analysis of the query and the plan, I would suggest indexes on the following to support the joins in the query: tblParents(studentID), tblAlumni(studentID), and tblStudentStudyYears(studentID, schoolYear). (The latter index indexes two columns to support a TOP 1 ordered lookup.) I am assuming that the following are already defined as primary-keys/clustered-indexes, so those table lookups do not need any additional index: tblStudents(studentID), tblGivingCampaigns(campaignID), tblGivingCallStatus(callStatusID), and tblGivingDonationStatus(donationStatusID).

Unless you have a lot of updates to the tblParents table, it's worth creating the suggested index to see if it gets you acceptable performance. And yes, you will have to modify this index if you add additional columns from the tblParents table in your Select statement. If the index doesn't improve performance, you can drop the index with no penalty.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
